# R: Find maximum of density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data with around 25,000 rows `myData` with column `attr` having values from 0 -> 45,600. I am not sure how to make a simplified or reproducible data...

Anyway, I am plotting the density of `attr` like below, and I also find the `attr` value where density is maximum:

```
library(ggplot)
max <- which.max(density(myData$attr)$y)
density(myData$attr)$x[max]
ggplot(myData, aes(x=attr))+ 
  geom_density(color="darkblue", fill="lightblue")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = density(myData$attr)$x[max])+
  xlab("attr")
```

Here is the plot I have got with the x-intercept at maximum point:
[image]

Since the data is skewed, I then attempted to draw x-axis in log scale by adding `scale_x_log10()` to the `ggplot`, here is the new graph:
[image]

My questions now are:

**1.** Why does it have 2 maximum points now? Why is my x-intercept no longer at the maximum point(s)?

**2.** How do I find the intercepts for the 2 new maximum points?

Finally, I attempt to convert the y-axis to `count` instead:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x=attr)) +
  stat_density(aes(y=..count..), color="black", fill="blue", alpha=0.3)+
  xlab("attr")+
  scale_x_log10()
```

I got the following plot:
[image]

**3.** How do I find the `count` of the 2 peaks?

Comment: It looks like ggplot is doing the log10 transformation before the density estimation, which has an effect because the bins are thus of different sizes

Comment: You mean it counts `log(attr)` instead of `attr`. Could you give an example? As I am not very clear about the log scale here

Comment: It's the difference between `plot(density(log10(mtcars$mpg)))` and 
`d <- density(mtcars$mpg);
d$x <- log10(d$x);
plot(d)`

Comment: just to add, to get the peaks you need to go down to the density function.. no way of getting it out of ggplot

Comment: @alistaire so in my case, how do I plot it the second way using ggplot? (density estimation first, log transformation second)

Comment: I don't think you can force the order in ggplot; it's simpler to do the density estimation beforehand: `d <- density(mtcars$mpg);
ggplot(data.frame(x = d$x, y = d$y), aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_density(stat = "identity") + 
    scale_x_log10()` You could use `geom_line()` instead if you don't care about the line on the bottom.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Why the density shapes are different

To put my comments into a fuller context, ggplot is taking the log before doing the density estimation, which is causing the difference in shape because the binning covers different parts of the domain. For example,

```r
(bins <- seq(1, 10, length.out = 10))
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
(bins_log <- 10^seq(log10(1), log10(10), length.out = 10))
#>  [1]  1.000000  1.291550  1.668101  2.154435  2.782559  3.593814  4.641589
#>  [8]  5.994843  7.742637 10.000000

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(bins, bins_log), 
                  trans = rep(c('identity', 'log10'), each = 10)), 
       aes(x, y = trans, col = trans)) + 
    geom_point()
```

[image: even bins vs log bins]

This binning can affect the resulting density shape. For example, compare an untransformed density:

```r
d <- density(mtcars$disp)
plot(d)
```

[image: linear bins]

to one which is logged beforehand:

```r
d_log <- density(log10(mtcars$disp))
plot(d_log)
```

[image: log before density]

Note that the height of the modes flips! I believe what you are asking for is the first one, but with the log transformation applied after the density, i.e.

```r
d_x_log <- d
d_x_log$x <- log10(d_x_log$x)
plot(d_x_log)
```

[image: density before logs]

Here the modes are similar, just compressed.

### Moving to ggplot

When moving to ggplot, to do the density estimation before the log transformation it's easiest to do it outside of ggplot beforehand:

```r
library(ggplot2)

d <- density(mtcars$disp)

ggplot(data.frame(x = d$x, y = d$y), aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_density(stat = "identity", fill = 'burlywood', alpha = 0.3) + 
    scale_x_log10()
```

[image: ggplot with density before log]

### Finding modes

Finding modes when there's a single one is relatively easy; it's just `d$x[which.max(d$x)]`. But when you have multiple modes, that's not good enough, since it will only show you the highest one. A solution is to effectively take the derivative and look for where the slope changes from positive to negative. We can do this numerically with `diff`, and since we only care about whether the result is positive or negative, call `sign` on that to turn everything into -1 and 1.* If we call `diff` on *that*, everything will be 0 except the maximums and minimums, which will be -2 and 2, respectively. We can then look for `which` values are less than 0, which we can use to subset. (Because `diff` does not insert `NA`s on the end, you'll have to add one to the indices.) Altogether, designed to work on a density object,

```r
d <- density(mtcars$disp)

modes <- function(d){
    i <- which(diff(sign(diff(d$y))) < 0) + 1
    data.frame(x = d$x[i], y = d$y[i])
}

modes(d)
#>          x           y
#> 1 128.3295 0.003100294
#> 2 305.3759 0.002204658

d$x[which.max(d$y)]    # double-check
#> [1] 128.3295
```

We can add them to our plot, and they'll get transformed nicely:

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = d$x, y = d$y), aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_density(stat = "identity", fill = 'mistyrose', alpha = 0.3) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = modes(d)$x) +
    scale_x_log10()
```

[image: logged ggplot with mode lines]

### Plotting counts instead of density

To turn the y-axis into counts instead of density, multiply y by the number of observations, which is stored in the density object as `n`:

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = d$x, y = d$y * d$n), aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_density(stat = "identity", fill = 'thistle', alpha = 0.3) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = modes(d)$x) +
    scale_x_log10()
```

[image: logged ggplot count density]

In this case it looks a little silly because there are only 32 observations spread over a wide domain, but with a larger n and smaller domain, it is more interpretable:

```r
d <- density(diamonds$carat, n = 2048)

ggplot(data.frame(x = d$x, y = d$y * d$n), aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_density(stat = "identity", fill = 'papayawhip', alpha = 0.3) + 
    geom_point(data = modes(d), aes(y = y * d$n)) +
    scale_x_log10()
```

[image: diamonds count density plot]

---

* Or 0 if the value is exactly 0, but that's unlikely here and will work fine regardless.

Comment: Wow! This is a very thorough reply that answers all my questions, and then some more. Thank you!

Comment: The conversion to counts does not work, as you can see the value in your final plot is higher than the total n in the diamonds data set. No idea why this is but yea.

Comment: Can someone guide me on how to get the modes for multiple density plots faceted ? This doesn't work:
mu <- df %>% 
  group_by(gp) %>%
  summarise(grp.mean = mean(x), grp.sd = sd(x), cnt=n(),grp.mdy=which.max(density(x)$y))